# Error while retrieving wishlist data

Tags: magento2, database, sql, wishlist

i am trying to  retrieving wishlist data and this error appears

```
[2020-06-22 08:41:10] report.CRITICAL: Report ID: webapi-5ef06ea694149; Message: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`magento`.`wishlist`, CONSTRAINT `WISHLIST_CUSTOMER_ID_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customer_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE), query was: INSERT INTO `wishlist` (`customer_id`, `sharing_code`, `updated_at`) VALUES (?, ?, '2020-06-22 08:41:10') {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 23000): Report ID: webapi-5ef06ea694149; Message: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`magento`.`wishlist`, CONSTRAINT `WISHLIST_CUSTOMER_ID_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customer_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE), query was: INSERT INTO `wishlist` (`customer_id`, `sharing_code`, `updated_at`) VALUES (?, ?, '2020-06-22 08:41:10') at /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php:208, Zend_Db_Statement_Exception(code: 23000): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`magento`.`wishlist`, CONSTRAINT `WISHLIST_CUSTOMER_ID_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customer_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE), query was: INSERT INTO `wishlist` (`customer_id`, `sharing_code`, `updated_at`) VALUES (?, ?, '2020-06-22 08:41:10') at /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php:110, PDOException(code: 23000): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`magento`.`wishlist`, CONSTRAINT `WISHLIST_CUSTOMER_ID_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customer_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) at /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php:91)"} []
```

**Please help me solve it.
Thanks**

Answer (score 1):

You have an issue on `wishlist` table.  This table has a duplicated record on some `customer_id` means You have tried to create a new record for the customer which already has recorded at this table. So, you have to delete existing record then run the insert query.

foreign key constraint fails magento`.`wishlist`, CONSTRAINT WISHLIST_CUSTOMER_ID_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID.

Or you have tried inserting a record which does not have customer_id value in insert query.

> INSERT INTO `wishlist` (`customer_id`, `sharing_code`, `updated_at`)
> VALUES (?, ?, '2020-06-22 08:41:10')

Comment: customer id was not there in customer_entity table. i manually created customer & run the query & it worked :)